# como usar pyautogui.locateOnScreen em so uma parte da tela

Tags: python, pyautogui

como eu faço para procurar uma imagem na tela com pyautogui.locateOnScreen em uma parte somente? tipo eu do as cordenadas de um quadrado e ele so vai procurar aquela imagem naquela area do quadrado.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi, você precisa pesquisar em uma área específica da tela.

Caso seja isso, você deve utilizar o locate, mas com a adição da região que você quer procurar. O "region" funciona conforme abaixo.

MODELO: region=(esquerda, topo, largura, altura)

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('imagem_a_ser_procurada.png', region=(0,0, 600, 800))
```

Neste exemplo você inicia a busca no canto esquerdo superior da tela "0,0" e procura em uma área padrão de "600x800", mesmo que seu monitor esteja em outra configuração maior.

Answer (score -3):

Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, mas de acordo com a documentação oficial: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html

você poderia fazer algo como

```py
import pyautogui
button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('calc7key.png')
button7location
Box(left=1416, top=562, width=50, height=41)
```

1. primeiro vc coloca a imagem que vc quer
2. depois ele gera as coordenadas da imagem